How to (manually) write the path in Nautilus/Files when downloading a document from browser using Ubuntu 22.04 with desktop environment GNOME 42.9
I am using Ubuntu 22.04 with desktop environment GNOME 42.9 and I find very handy to use Ctrl + l to (manually) write the path in Nautilus/Files to browse my file. However, If I want to download a file to a specific location and use Ctrl + l shortcut, this edits the name of the file to be downloaded and not the path. How is it possible to edit the path when downloading a file?

In a "Save" dialog, you immediately get to see a bar to edit the name, so there is no use for a shortcut key such as Ctrl+L to display an editable box.
To edit the path, type a character recognized as indicating the start of a path:

/ for starting an absolute path, i.e., starting from "root" ('/')
~ for starting from your home directory
. for starting a relative path from the current directory
.. for starting a relative path from the parent directory

You type or paste the full path. You can also make use of the autosuggestions. As soon as you enter one of these characters, drop-down suggestions will appear. You can select one and hit Enter to include the suggestion in the pathname.

many thanks for the clear answer!
